# Event to know usercontrol's disposal?

Tags: c#, wpf

if a window with usercontrol is getting closed, then i should call a method in the usercontrol i.e. nothing but when usercontrol is disposed. How do i do that?

Comment: Have you tried overriding `Dispose(bool)`?

Comment: Ershad, try to detail your question a bit more - we're not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know when the garbage collector collects the `UserControl` use this:

```
    ~UserControl1()
    {
        //...
    }
```

If you want to know when the `UserControl` is unloaded from its parent, use `Unloaded` event on the userControl

note: unlike a `Window`, a `UserControl` can't get closed.

Comment: This would only be called when the gc collects the object. Not at the moment the user closes the parent

Comment: Interestingly, I get the error `The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item`. I'm using .NET 4.6.

Comment: @ThyArtIsCode you are correct. destructor methods does not accept access modifiers such as public, protected,... I updated the answer.

Comment: Unloaded event is fired when the control is hosted inside TabControl, each time user switches tabs away from my control.

Answer (score 0):

As contols do not have a Closing/Closed event it's not that simple as overriding Dispose. Dispose may not be called under some circumstances.

You might override WndProc of the control and catch the WM_CLOSE event.

Answer (score -1):

For future reference for others..

I disposed my user control that was loaded by my main window like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Class" ... Unloaded="UserControl_Unloaded"></UserControl>

private void UserControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MyVM)this.DataContext).Dispose();
}
```

`Unloaded` is an event available on any View.

Comment: I advise everyone to stay away from the ``Unloaded`` event. It can fire even when the control is alive and well. Check the MSDN docs for more info. In my case it fired on a control that was a child of a tab item in a tab control when switching between the tabs.